# Java 8 Update 351 treating SHA-1 jarfiles as unsigned, is there a workaround?

Tags: java-8, sha1, jnlp

When launching a JNLP application with Java 8 update 351, the following error is received:

> **```
> ERROR:  Unsigned application requesting unrestricted access to system
> Unsigned resoured: xyz.jar

The release notes for update 351 include "JARs signed with SHA-1 algorithms are now restricted by default and treated as if they were unsigned."

There is a suggested workaround of "set allow_weak_crypto = true in the krb5.conf configuration file to re-enable them", but there is no krb5.conf file anywhere to be found (Windows 10 install).

Has anyone encountered and resolved this issue?  Thank you.

Looked for krb5.conf file, could not find any.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the block on SHA1 in the java.security file on the client system and re-download the JNLP file.

So it looks as if you'd remove these lines from examples below -

",SHA1 usage SignedJAR & denyAfter 2019-01-01"
",SHA1 denyAfter 2019-01-01"

https://www.java.com/en/configure_crypto.html

Use one of the following two methods to find out if your signed JARs may be affected by this change:

For JDK 7u301, 8u291, 11.0.11, 17 or later releases, edit the java.security file and make the following changes:

add "SHA1 usage SignedJAR & denyAfter 2019-01-01" to the jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms security property
add "SHA1 denyAfter 2019-01-01" to the jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms security property

For example, if the current value of these properties is:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer, \
    RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224
jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024, \
    DSA keySize < 1024
then the new values would be:
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer, \
    RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, \
    SHA1 usage SignedJAR & denyAfter 2019-01-01
jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024, \
    DSA keySize < 1024, SHA1 denyAfter 2019-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Mike, we saw a similar error after updating to JRE351.
Our workaround is in the 'java.security' file, remove the following lines:
SHA1 usage SignedJAR & denyAfter 2019-01-01
SHA1 denyAfter 2019-01-01